# Expo image picker uri does not work on every phone

Tags: image, react-native, expo

I am using Expo to build a React Native app. I want users to be able to save a profile picture. I have been trying this for months. I use Expo image picker to do this. However, the file I am getting back is in the local system. When I try to log in to another phone the image is not showing up, probably because it is restricted only to the phone the image was being fetched from. I read an article about removing file:// on iOS but it doesn't work anyway. In the backend, I am using GraphQL and I am just storing the photoUrl as a string in a MongoDB database. I mean, there are a lot of React Native apps out there so there must be a simple solution to this.

Code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
      const {
        status,
      } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert(
          'Vi behöver din profilbild för att göra det lättare för andra användare att veta vem du är'
        );
      }
    }
  })();
}, []);

const pickImage = async () => {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
    quality: 1,
  });

  if (!result.cancelled && Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    const photo = result?.uri.replace('file://', '/private');

    setPhotoUrl(photo);
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context about how the app is talking to your backend? Is the backend hosted on a server or just local host?

For the file to be accessible between different devices, there will need to be some persistence outside of the phone's local file system (because your phone can't just 'know' about another phone running the app).

Comment: Yeah, so I am using Apolloserver to handle requests. First of, yes the server is hosted on localhost for now. I have a simple typeDef for users where one field is photoUrl: String. When a user creates an account they enter all the information and submit an image. I don't modify the uri from expo image picker, I just send store it to my mongodb database. What I am really asking is how to store a url for every users image universal to all devices. Without file://. I also tried the base64 version but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the local image uri for upload method, so when you try to fetch it back it cannot because the uri you are uploading to db is the local uri.

You have to use a blob storage and configure your backend...

Steps:

- get file name from the local uri
- upload the image to blob storage
- save blob url in yout db as 'string' (eg: https://yourblobstorage/profilepicture/filename.png)
- best idea is to change the file name to userid or some kind of unique id.
- so every time you fetch this url from your blob for this user
- and you do the same for change profilepicture (so the user profilepicture name is always his user id, which makes it simple for you and saves some space XD)

My implementation:

Image picker method:

```
  const addCameraImage = async () => {
setOverlayVisible(false)
const { granted } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()

if (granted === true) {
  let image = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [1, 1],
    quality: 1,
  })

  await uploadImage(image)

} else {
  setPermissionOverlayVisible(true)
}
}
```

upload image method:

```
  const uploadImage = async (image: ImagePicker.ImagePickerResult) => {
if (image.cancelled === false) {
  setLocalImage(image.uri)
  const filename = image.uri.split('/').pop();

  const file = new ReactNativeFile({
    uri: image.uri,
    name: filename,
    type: `image/${filename.split('.').pop()}`
  });

  try {
    await updateProfilePictureMutation({
      variables: {
        id: data?.user?.id,
        profilePicture: file
      },
      update: (cache, { data }) => {
        try {
          const getUserByIdCachedData = cache.readQuery<GetUserByIdQuery>({ query: GetUserByIdDocument, variables: { id: userId } })
          if (!getUserByIdCachedData) return

          const newData = {
            ...getUserByIdCachedData,
            user: {
              ...getUserByIdCachedData.user,
              profilePicture: data.updateUser.profilePicture
            }
          }

          cache.writeQuery({ query: GetUserByIdDocument, variables: { id: userId }, data: newData })
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e)
        }
      }
    })
  } catch (e) {
  }

  setLocalImage(null)
}
}
```

open a modal which asks user persmission to open settings to enable permission if they have already denied before and tries to take a picture:

```
  const openSettings = () => {
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
  setPermissionOverlayVisible(false)
}
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  const pkg = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel ? Constants.manifest.android.package : 'host.exp.exponent'
  IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
    IntentLauncher.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
    { data: 'package:' + pkg }
  )
  setPermissionOverlayVisible(false)
}
}
```

Now here I set the local image as soon as they take a picture so they dont have to wait for the time you upload the picture to blob, once its uploaded, i fetch from blob

```
  const getAvatarImage = () => {
if (updateProfilePictureLoading) return null
if (localImage) {
  return { uri: localImage }
}

if (data?.user?.profilePicture) {
  return { uri: data?.user?.profilePicture }
}

return null
}
```

I hope this helps you understand a little bit more, I was stuggling with this so much, but later I realized its quite simple.

I have also made mutation and query for my upload and fetching from blob on backend.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks so much. It finally works. This was the only problem I have left before I can deploy the app, I have been trying and trying for like six months. Thx so much!

Comment: @jacob please do be conscious  about ios and android version of permission... Make your  permissions clear and why.. also make a open modal when the user tries to access camera when they have already denied permission. its just a good user flow.

Comment: also based on my experience, whith image picker and permission, you need camera permission and media library permission for ios, and for android just mediaLibrary permission will do fine for both. 

or ios store will reject your application to upload to store.  

hence, I use a modal to educate the user and give me both media and camera permission before invoking the native permission popup.

Comment: do I create a blob through a service like Amazon S3 or can you do it directly through Expo?

Comment: You can use any services, amazon, Microsoft azure.. or any other storage provider of your choice. I personally use Microsoft azure for my services. Good practice is to create a blob and make it private, and you fetch the blob with your api.. and api asks the storage provider with a  unique key for that user's picture. hence its more secure for the user.

Comment: when I fetch the image, do I set the uri of the image as something like `photoUrl.uri` or just the entire object?

Comment: set the remote uri to the image. and you can cache it. on the update method update a new profile picture on the same url and do a refetch. so the new image gets cached